# live execute git command on PHP

Tags: php, linux, git, console, exec

I've been try to clone repository with PHP, why the output only show me

`cloning into project-name` ? 
and not show me next message like

**remote : enumerating objects**

**remote : counting objects**

**receiving object 19% (591/3095), 5.06 MiB | 1024.00 KiB/s**

[image: git SS]

here is my function to execute live command

```
ob_implicit_flush(true);ob_end_flush();

function liveExecuteCommand($cmd)
{

    // while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

    $proc = popen("$cmd 2>&1 ; echo Exit status : $?", 'r');

    $live_output     = "";
    $complete_output = "";

    while (!feof($proc))
    {
        $live_output     = fread($proc, 4096);
        $complete_output = $complete_output . $live_output;
        echo "$live_output";
        // @ flush();
    }

    pclose($proc);

    // get exit status
    preg_match('/[0-9]+$/', $complete_output, $matches);

    // return exit status and intended output
    return array (
                    'exit_status'  => intval($matches[0]),
                    'output'       => str_replace("Exit status : " . $matches[0], '', $complete_output)
                 );
}
```

and then i call the function :

```
liveExecuteCommand('git clone https://username:password@gitlab.com/example/project.git');
```

Anyone can help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `--progress` switch.

From the **git-clone(1)** man page:

> Progress status is reported on the standard error stream by default
>   when it is attached to a terminal, unless -q is specified. This flag
>   forces progress status even if the standard error stream is not
>   directed to a terminal.

You should run `git clone` like this:

```
liveExecuteCommand('git clone --progress https://username:password@gitlab.com/example/project.git');
```

The problem is:

1. When you run `git clone` in your shell, you are attached to a terminal and these buffered streams work nicely (you can see the counters moving, etc.. like an interactive interface)
2. When your code runs via PHP it's not attached to a terminal and therefore this sort of output will be total garbage (i.e: lots of lines of updates of the counters until it reaches 100%, etc..)

You can go around this using some hacks. One of them is installing `expect` which also provides `unbuffer` that can take care of this problem.

```
liveExecuteCommand('unbuffer git clone --progress https://username:password@gitlab.com/example/project.git');
```

Also, check if it helps wrapping your `echo "$live_output"` with `echo nl2br($live_output)` if you'll be printing to a web page.